# saga test case giving this issue

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, redux, redux-saga

SO i have this function in my saga file

```
 export default function* rootSaga ()
{
  yield all ([
    
      testfunction(),
  ])
}
```

For this I am writing this case for this function ,

```
   it ("SagaRoot",() => {
   const generator = rootSaga ();
   const testfunction = jest.fn();
  
   expect (generator.next.value).toEqual(all([testfunction]));
  })
```

And I am getting error here

```
expected - [Function mockConstructor],
received  + GeneratorFunctionPrototype {},
```

what can be done here ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

*"redux-saga": "^1.1.3"*

There are some issues in your code.

1. The effect creator [`all([...effects])`](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#alleffects---parallel-effects) accepts effects as its argument, not plain JS function.
2. You don't need to create a mock function, just use the original `testFunction`. Testing the saga generator function step-by-step will not run the `testFunction`. The saga generator function only yields effects rather than the return value of `testFunction`.
3. [`next()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator/next) is a method, not a property.

E.g.

`saga.ts`:

```
import { all, call } from "redux-saga/effects";

export const testfunction = () => 'test'

export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([
    call(testfunction),
  ])
}
```

`saga.test.ts`:

```
import { all, call } from "redux-saga/effects";
import rootSaga, { testfunction } from "./saga";

it("SagaRoot", () => {
  const generator = rootSaga();
  expect(generator.next().value).toEqual(all([call(testfunction)]));
  expect(generator.next().value).toEqual(undefined);
})
```

Test result:

```
 PASS   redux-saga-examples  packages/redux-saga-examples/src/stackoverflow/76481662/saga.test.ts
  ✓ SagaRoot (3 ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |   83.33 |      100 |      50 |     100 |                   
 saga.ts  |   83.33 |      100 |      50 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.202 s
```

Comment: Thanks ! This is not working and giving same error